# Different Coupons for Different Products in same cart

Tags: cart, shopping-cart-price-rules, discount, coupon-codes

I have `5` items in my cart, say `A, B, C, D and E`. and I want to apply `10 %` discount of Item `A` and `5 %` discount on item `B` and no discounts on the rest.
How can this be achieved?

Comment: https://docs.magento.com/m1/ce/user_guide/marketing/price-rules-shopping-cart.html -Follow this

Comment: You can not apply multiple coupons in same cart.